# React hooks not updating state properly with dynamic naming

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component, which is used to make a login request to my server.

It is inside a modal, where I'm using Material UI

```js
 <TextField
            onChange={handleChange}
            autoFocus
            name="email"
            margin="dense"
            id="email"
            label="Email Address"
            type="email"
            fullWidth
          />
           <TextField
           onChange={handleChange}
            autoFocus
            name="password"
            margin="dense"
            id="password"
            label="Password"
            type="password"
            fullWidth
          />
```

Then i have this state along with a handler to set the state properly.

```js
    const [state, setState] = React.useState({
        email: '',
        password: '',
        valid: false
    })

    const handleChange = (event) =>{
        event.preventDefault()
        console
        setState((state) => ({[event.target.name]: event.target.value, ...state}))
        if(state.email.length !== 0 && state.password.length !== 0){
            setState((state) => ({valid: true, ...state}))
        }
    }
```

However when ever the function is called, i con log out the `syntheticEvent` and get the correct values, but nothing is being set, when i log out the state afterwards. I have little experience in working with complete state objects, with hooks, so i can't really figure out the issue.

The name property is null, after the function is called three times and i get this warning

```
This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `target` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist().
```

Comment: If the answer doesn't work try making a producible minimal example: https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-starter-n2dem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the warning suggests, try updating the state once:

```
const handleChange = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  setState(state => {
    const { email, password } = state;
    const valid = email.length !== 0 && password.length !== 0;
    return { [name]: value, valid, ...state };
  });
};
```